# Include timestamp in a xmpp pubsub item

Tags: xmpp, openfire, ejabberd

I read all those discussions and mailing lists which propose how to standardize the inclusion of a timestamp in a pubsub item but there is no answer how it is done practically today. Do I have to tweak my server to include the creation timestamp (because each server stores that information for some reason ;) or are there plugins or known source code modifications for openfire or ejabberd?

I have entries which are published in json format and not in Atom. BTW where the "published" and "updated" timestamps come from in the XEP-0060? Will the timestamp be added automatically if I configure the node to publish in Atom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to tweak your server, since the timestamp is not part of the spec.

The only way to have timestamps right now, is to put them in at the application level, which means the publisher is inserting it into the payload.